# Search icon is getting displayed twice in Toolbar in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement a search functionality in my application.
I am trying to display search icon in toolbar, but instead of single search icon multiple icons are getting displayed. One icon is getting displayed from menu.xml file and other icon is getting displayed from the line `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`.

If I do not use "`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`" line then `onOptionsItemSelectedMenu` method will not get called, if I do not give search icon in `menu.xml` file then search icon will not get displayed. Please let me know how to come out of the issue. I am trying hard with no fruits. Please help me come out of this issue.

My current toolbar looks as shown in the image below:

[image: ToolBar]

My menu.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.blo.ifo.ifocusblogs.ActivityForFragments">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_label"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Comment: can you post your activity layout file, and any other menu xml that are in your project? Also check if there is already a call  to onCreateOptionsMenu(). Note that setHasOptionsMenu(true) never sets icons by default unless they are defined in some layout file.

Comment: I have resolved this issue long back. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 
[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qGnX.png)

and this was the solution that I've found:
add "menu.clear();" to "onPrepareOptionsMenu" in MainActivity
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVVcm.png)

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
    MenuItem itemSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) itemSearch.getActionView();

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    mSearchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.searchProduct));

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                adapter.getFilter().filter("");
                listview.clearTextFilter();
            }else {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```